# Data nucleus spatial mapping error

Tags: java, jpa, gis, spatial, datanucleus

I was trying to connect spatial types with datanucleus.

I have in database field called pla_location in "place" table, which is mysql GEOMETRY type

I did mapping as below:

```
<entity class="com.dn.dntest.model.Place">
<table name="place" schema="map"/>
    <attributes>
    ...
    <basic name="plaLocation">
        <column name="pla_location" />
    </basic>            
    ...
```

In Place java object I have:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

public class Place implements java.io.Serializable {
...
private Geometry plaLocation;

...
(getters and setters)
...
```

And now I'm asking database through "query"

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select a FROM com.dn.dntest.model.Place as a");
List results = q.getResultList();
```

And the result is

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'P.PLALOCATION' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
```

**But if I change the Geometry type to for instance String, everything works well - but, of course I will have string instead of Geometry :)**

Does it mean that data nucleus doesn't support spatial in JPA (only JDO)? 
I couldn't find any example for JPA spatial in data nucleus - and this is a basic mapping!
May someone will know how to resolve this problem

Versions: 
datanucleus-core 3.0.6
datanucleus-rdbms 3.0.6
datanucleus-api-jpa 3.0.6
datanucleus-spatial 3.0.1

Database mysql

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNucleus obviously supports use of spatial types on JDO or JPA, since DataNucleus "core" and store plugins are all API independent. I can persist a "JTS" Geometry field to MySQL with no problems using either JDO or JPA. Obviously JPA orm.xml doesn't allow specification of the "no-userdata" extension as part of the standard ... but you can define like this

```
<basic name="geom">
    <extension vendor-name="datanucleus" key="mapping" value="no-userdata"/>
</basic>
```

Comment: It sounds good but I have an xml incompatibility (orm_1_0.xsd) - i saw this structure in JDO only - but ok I will check this. 
I use xml because I read in some forum that datanucleus doesn't support annotation (only xml orm) - is this a still true ?

Comment: Do you believe all you read on the internet? It's total nonsense. DataNucleus has supported annotations and/or XML since JPA1. Use "orm_2_0.xsd" and DataNucleus resolves it to its own copy ... with <extension> included.

Comment: Oh big sorry I wrote something else than i thought. I mean, does GAE support annotation ?

Comment: You're not using GAE. And obviously GAE's DataNucleus plugin allows annotations since JDO/JPA annotations are plastered all over their docs. The term "fully compliant" springs to mind here.

Comment: Yep I know, it was only mental shortcut. Thanks for help!